# Trivial morphism between local cohomology groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, local-cohomology, schubert-varieties, schubert-cells

I have two questions concerning morphism between local cohomology groups which I think are related.

Let $G$ be a reductive group with Weyl group $W$ and $B \subset G$ a Borel. Let $X=G/B$ be the flag variety, $C(w)=BwB/B \subset X$ the Schubert cell associated to $w \in W$, and $X(w)$ its closure. Additionally fix an abelian sheaf $\mathcal{F} \in \mathit{Ab}(X)$.

1. Let $v,w \in W$ with $l(w)=l(v)+1$ and we abbreviate $\operatorname{codim}(C(w))$ by $c_w$. In Kempf's paper "[The Grothendieck–Cousin complex of an induced representation](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90021-X)" he mentions in a remark  after Lemma 12.6 that $H^{c_w}_{C(w)}(X,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow H^{c_v}_{C(v)}(X,\mathcal{F})$ is trivial if $C(v) \not\subset X(w)$ (equivalently $v \nleq w$) and says that it follows by trivial support related reasons. But unfortunately I don't see the concrete argumentation. So how does it follow in more detail?

2. Let $v,w \in W$ with $l(w)=l(v)$ and $v\neq w$. Is it then also true that $H^i_{X(w)}(X,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow H^i_{X(v)}(X,\mathcal{F})$ is trivial in general or at least for $i=c_w$? (Notice that the local cohomology groups vanish for $i<c_w=c_v$.)

Comment: What you quote in (1) is not quite what the remark says; it says rather that $H^{c_w}_{C(w)}(U_{c_w}, \mathcal F) \to H^{c_v}_{C(v)}(U_{c_v}, \mathcal F)$ is $0$, where $U_i$ is the complement of the union of codimension-($i + 1$) Schubert varieties.  (This is important, because individual cells are usually not closed in $X$.)

Comment: Here he is using the material before the lemma, which gives a map $H^{c_w}_{C(w)}(U_{c_w}, \mathcal F) \to \bigoplus_{C'} H^{c_v}_{C'}(U_{c_v}, \mathcal F)$, where $C'$ runs over the Bruhat cells of codimension $c_v$.  The map $H^{c_w}_{C(w)}, \mathcal F) \to H^{c_v}_{C(v)}(U_{c_v}, \mathcal F)$ is projection on the $C(v)$ factor (i.e., restricting the section to $C(v)$); but a section with support in $C(w) \subseteq U_{c_w}$ has support in $X(w) \cap U_{c_v} \subseteq U_{c_v}$.  In particular, its support does not intersect $C(v)$ unless $C(v) \subseteq X(w)$.

Comment: To your first answer. I think it doesn't matter as we have the excision isomorphism $H^{c_w}_{C(w)}(X,\mathcal{F})\cong H^{c_w}_{C(w)}(U_{c_w},\mathcal{F})$. Local cohomology is defined for locally closed subsets if you look for example at  "Local cohomology" by Hartshorne/Grothendieck.